# Is there a device or piece of software that can act as a transparent Ethernet bridge and limit bandwidth on MAC by MAC basis?

Tags: networking, ethernet

So for example, it will only let a particular MAC address on side A use 100kbps in ether direction.

Comment: Can you explain how the device you're after is different from a router?

Comment: You can use it for traffic shaping for not IP traffic. Like NetBIOS over IEEE 802.2, or IPX/SPX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure a Linux bridge with `ebtables` to mark the packets and `tc` to shape the traffic.

Also some Cisco switches can do bandwidth limiting. See [Cisco:Comparing Traffic Policing and Traffic Shaping for Bandwidth Limiting](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk543/tk545/technologies_tech_note09186a00800a3a25.shtml)

Answer (score 3):

[Untangle](http://untangle.com) can do this via the paid bandwidth control app.

Comment: I don't believe Untangle does this on a MAC basis, rather an IP/Protocol basis.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the info about this. I'll give it a try as well.

Comment: The new 11.2 version of Untangle released today now supports MAC address-based rules.

Answer (score 1):

I typically use [dummynet in FreeBSD](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/) (picoBSD, really) on a floppy or bootable USB token (or in a Virtual Machine) to do this. But you can also do it with iptables in Linux, some configurable switches, and specialty devices like [this one](http://minimaxwell.iwl.com/) or other WAN/LAN emulators.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution - m0n0wall, designed to test latency in applications which work over network.